# React with Firebase need to query Firebase if username exists before creating account - get true/false without getting the entire object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have a 'create account' component in my react app - I am able to create an account if I just use `auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword` function, but I decided I want the user to have a username as well. My logic is to

1. check the FB database for a `user_profile` that has a property of `username`
2. if any row has the `username` I'm looking for, then return `true` and tell user the `username` is already taken.

In `MySQL` I would have done something like this: `SELECT id FROM user_profiles WHERE username = $username;` -> this would return a result set with either the 'id' of the row that contains the specific username OR would return null/empty/etc when no row was found to have username.

IF the FB user is authenticated then I can use this:

```
firebase
    .database()
    .ref(userProfilesDatabase)
    .orderByChild('username')
    .equalTo('someusername')
    .once('value')
    .then(function(snapshot) {
        var username = snapshot.val().username;
        console.log(snapshot.val());
    });
```

This call above will NOT work because of my security rules/permission denied AND it also retrieves the entire object containing all the data, exposing `user_profile` data that I do not want to expose to a user who has yet to create an account - I just want to have `true` or `false` when username exists/does not exist.

My current DB schema looks like this (in `JSON` format, but hopefully it is clear), where 'user_profiles' is the table name, and each object inside is an ID for the user_profile that corresponds to the object that contains the username I need to check for along side other properties:

```
user_profiles

    8jgEZxuO7rbQAc8j8GdwIRgeqGG3
        age: 25
        username: someusername

    37ffEZsd338j8GdwIRgdfsDFreER
        age: 25
        username: anotherusername

    ....
```

My security rules look like this and I do not know how to add specific rules to a table - the documentation seems scattered all over the place and difficult to follow:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null"
  }
}
```